# Check if any radio button is checked, than execute code (multiple sets of buttons)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, radio-button

I made a multiple choice test with parsing XML of questions and answers using PHP. The generated HTML looks something like this:

```
<form>
<div id="category0">
    <div id="set0">
        <div class="question">What is 6 x 6?</div>
        <input type="radio" name="0" value="3">3<br>
        <input type="radio" name="0" value="30">30<br>
        <input type="radio" name="0" value="36">36<br>
        <input type="hidden" class="answer" value="36">
    </div>
    <div id="set1">
        <div class="question">What is 2 x 6?</div>
        <input type="radio" name="1" value="4">4<br>
        <input type="radio" name="1" value="12">12<br>
        <input type="radio" name="1" value="36">43<br>
        <input type="hidden" class="answer" value="12">
    </div>
    <!-- A LOT MORE QUESTIONS -->
</div>
<div id="category1">
    <div id="set2">
        <div class="question">Which of these tools would you use to hammer a nail?</div>
        <input type="radio" name="2" value="A hammer">A hammer<br>
        <input type="radio" name="2" value="Another nail">Another nail<br>
        <input type="radio" name="2" value="A saw">A saw<br>
        <input type="hidden" class="answer" value="A hammer">
    </div>
    <div id="set3">
        <div class="question">What color is a red truck?</div>
        <input type="radio" name="3" value="red">red<br>
        <input type="radio" name="3" value="blue">blue<br>
        <input type="radio" name="3" value="green">green<br>
        <input type="hidden" class="answer" value="red">
    </div>
    <!-- A LOT MORE QUESTIONS -->
</div>  
<!-- MORE CATEGORIES WITH A LOT OF QUESTIONS-->
</form>
```

Categories are named "Category" + a number starting from 0 (category0, category1...)
The answer is stored in a hidden field and is exactly the same as the correct options value.

I created a JS function that checks if the selected answer is correct or not, and colors the background of set div according. The function is triggered onclick in each radio input.

I need help with creating a statistic/score of answers for all questions and for each category separately. 
At the beginning the score would be 0 of all possible answers.
If I would click on the correct choice of first question the score would be 1 of all possible questions, and 1 of all questions of first category.

I would like to achive this live (when any button is clicked), without posting the form(no POST/GET).

Hope I described my problem so you can understand it, if any clarification is needed, please let me know.
So far I only worked with JS, but any solutions in jQuery as also welcome.

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript you tried. Without it, this question is pretty broad and it looks like you're asking us to code the entire solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

When a radio button is clicked, execute the same logic you already have to determine if answers are correct, but call it for EACH of your "categories", NOT just the one that was clicked.

Start a variable at 0 and increment it by 1 each time you find a correct answer.  Then, after your loop, you can update your "Correct Answers" message with the variable's value.  This won't require any postbacks.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful! I was looking for too complicated solutions. Will post my solution or ask for help if i get stuck again.

Comment: No problem - and you could add how many they left blank, if you don't have any controls in place to ensure each question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').change( function(){
  var answer = $(this).siblings('.answer').val();
  if ($(this).val() == answer) {
    var score = $(this).parents().siblings('.score').val();
    score++;
    $(this).parents().siblings('.score').val(score)
    console.log(score);
  } else {
    
    }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<div id="category0">
    <div id="set0">
        <div class="question">What is 6 x 6?</div>
        <input type="radio" name="0" value="3">3<br>
        <input type="radio" name="0" value="30">30<br>
        <input type="radio" name="0" value="36">36<br>
        <input type="hidden" class="answer" value="36">
    </div>
    <div id="set1">
        <div class="question">What is 2 x 6?</div>
        <input type="radio" name="1" value="4">4<br>
        <input type="radio" name="1" value="12">12<br>
        <input type="radio" name="1" value="36">43<br>
        <input type="hidden" class="answer" value="12">
    </div>
  <input type="hidden" class="score" value="0">
    <p></p>
    <!-- A LOT MORE QUESTIONS -->
</div>
<div id="category1">
    <div id="set2">
        <div class="question">Which of these tools would you use to hammer a nail?</div>
        <input type="radio" name="2" value="A hammer">A hammer<br>
        <input type="radio" name="2" value="Another nail">Another nail<br>
        <input type="radio" name="2" value="A saw">A saw<br>
        <input type="hidden" class="answer" value="A hammer">
    </div>
    <div id="set3">
        <div class="question">What color is a red truck?</div>
        <input type="radio" name="3" value="red">red<br>
        <input type="radio" name="3" value="blue">blue<br>
        <input type="radio" name="3" value="green">green<br>
        <input type="hidden" class="answer" value="red">
    </div>
  <input type="hidden" class="score" value="0">
  <p><p>
    <!-- A LOT MORE QUESTIONS -->
</div>  
<!-- MORE CATEGORIES WITH A LOT OF QUESTIONS-->
</form>
```